# System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I am getting the below exception randomly from a C# based client connecting to Java based server. This error comes randomly on the user machine in production; after sometime when connection is restarted by the C# client it works.

There is no consistency in occurring this error. Sometimes it works days without this error, otherwise it occurs in every few hours.

The issue due to firewall/anti-virus should not be there because it is not failing every time or there is no fixed time of the day when it fails.

> Details: System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in
>   your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186355/unable-to-write-data-to-the-transport-vs2017-asp-net-core-scaffolding-mssql-w/43192121?noredirect=1#comment73467667_43192121

Answer (score 0):

It should be the underlying network connection or also the application architecture. You have to check the whole [OSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) model. Your question is too broad. Please give some details.